# How to recursively create 1 gb files in random locations

Tags: filesystem, storage

I need to create a bunch of 1 GB files in random locations of my file system and have this process repeat over and over again. I don't care whether the files are filled with random data or if they are empty, I just need to fill up the system with these files. I would like to be able to create them all with the same name.

If anyone has any answers, please share. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean recursively? What would you be recursing into? Do you mean in random subdirectories? Also "*I would like to be able to create them all with the same*": the same what? The same command?

Comment: recursively, as in over and over again without stopping. I just need a bunch of files scattered all over the file system, in random directories and I need it done very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will create 10 files, of 1GB each at random locations in your file system:

```
find / -mount -type d -print0 2>/dev/null | 
    shuf -zn 10 | 
        while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do 
            sudo fallocate -l 1G "$dir"/evilFile && 
            echo "Created $dir/evilFile"; 
        done
```

#### Explanation

- `find / -mount -type d -print0 2>/dev/null` : find all directories in your `/`. The `-moun` tells `find` not to descend into mounted filesystems. This is optional, but a good idea if you have any mounted network shares or the like. Then, the `-print0` means "end each line with a NULL (`\0`) instead of a newline (`\n`)". You need this in case any of the directory names you find contain a newline. Finally, the `2>/dev/null` is to discard error mesages about not having permission to read directories. You could also avoid this by running the `find` command as root, but this is risky enough without going into system directories.
- `shuf -zn 10` : choose 10 lines randomly. The `-z` lets `shuf` deal with NULL-terminated lines.
- `while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do` : read each null-terminated line, saving each directory as `$dir` and...
- `sudo fallocate -l 1G "$dir"/evilFile` : create a 1G file in that directory.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was going for. is "evilFile" the name of the file?

Comment: @TheMATEMan yes.